# Ruby On Rails - Use .html request format if .mobile file doesn't exist

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobile, railscasts

I followed http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices and implemented

```
request.format = :mobile if mobile_device?
```

But it's pretty stupid and sometimes confusing if I just need to copy the same html in the .mobile files. Is there any way to use the .html files if the .mobile files don't exist?

I was thinking about using something like

```
<%= render 'path/to/htmlfile' %>
```

in the .mobile files, but I hope there is a better option.

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.0.2

Comment: You might want to see what Rails 4.1 can do for you with Variants: http://brewhouse.io/blog/2013/12/17/whats-new-in-rails-4-1.html#action-pack-variants